# Some websites fail to load on Linux only

Tags: networking, kubuntu, dns

I've just installed Kubuntu 17.04 on my PC which previously had Windows 10.

I am using Mozilla Firefox and some websites (e.g. `github.com`) fail to load, while other websites (e.g. `youtube.com`) work just fine.

I am using wireless connection.

This issue happened few times on my laptop which also uses Kubuntu 17.04 while using wired connection (to the same router) and I would fix it by unplugging and plugging wire back in. However, reconnecting to connection doesn't solve issue.

Command `sudo iptables -S`:

Output:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Command: `sudo ifconfig`

Output:

```
enp6s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 50:e5:49:36:22:95  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 424  bytes 31388 (31.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 424  bytes 31388 (31.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp4s7: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.24  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255                                                                                            
        inet6 fe80::3089:963e:7f8a:2c5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>                                                                                             
        ether 5e:df:dd:a5:88:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)                                                                                                         
        RX packets 15410  bytes 16443953 (16.4 MB)                                                                                                                   
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0                                                                                                                  
        TX packets 14127  bytes 1780416 (1.7 MB)                                                                                                                     
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Command: `route`

Output:

```
Kernel IP routing table                                                                                                                                              
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface                                                                                        
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s7                                                                                       
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp4s7                                                                                       
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s7
```

Command: `cat /etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost                                                                                                                                            
127.0.1.1       home                                                                                                                                                 

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts                                                                                                           
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback                                                                                                                                   
fe00::0 ip6-localnet                                                                                                                                                 
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix                                                                                                                                              
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes                                                                                                                                                 
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Command: `ip -6 route`

Output:

```
fe80::/64 dev wlp4s7 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium
```

Command: `ping github.com`
Output: `ping: github.com: Name or service not known`

This is not first time I had this issue. Same happened on laptop with Gnome desktop environment and Ubuntu 16.04, as well as KDE 16.04, a year ago.

Google is full of questions like this, but all of them are either unanswered or their answers are unrelated to my issue.

[image]

Comment: What's the output of `ip -6 route`?

Comment: @vidarlo `fe80::/64 dev wlp4s7 proto kernel metric 256  pref medium`

Comment: what's the error of the browser?

Comment: @AmirForsatiQ. It is the same screen as the one when you have no connection at all. Firefox has some hints about troubleshoting, while Chrome has the dino game.

Comment: Do `ping` command work too?

Comment: @AmirForsatiQ. Yes `ping` works. I remember when I just installed it, two days ago, I used it to test packages as described in answer (while googling this same problem, I think it was some SO answer with 40 upvotes, gonna try to find link tho).

Comment: i mean for those websites, do ping works for websites wont open in browser?

Comment: @AmirForsatiQ. It's strange. Github page works now again. It happened few times, sometimes it works, and then next day on boot it doesn't. So I can't really test `ping` command on the website that doesn't work at this moment. I will run `ping` command on websites that will fail to load again, once it starts breaking again. I am sorry for making this delay, it's really strange behavior.

Comment: I think would be a network problem.

Comment: @AmirForsatiQ. Hi, I've added `ping` output. GitHub doesn't work again while AskUbuntu loads just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your internet connection is not working properly.Specifically your DNS is not resolving properly.

Try to add the line

```
nameserver 80.80.80.80
```

To your

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

*This will add the freenom DNS server temporarily **until the next boot***